# How to make keyboard shortcut to log into shh and keept terminal open

Tags: keyboard, ssh, shortcuts

I'd like to make a keyboard shortcut on Ubuntu 20.10 which logs into ssh and keeps the terminal open.

So far I've managed to make a script "ssh.sh" which works in the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@SERVER
```

I made this executable with:

```
chmod -x ssh.sh
```

I put this in keyboard shortcuts:

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

but it doesn't seem to work when I press the key bindings.

How would I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, the shell `sh` is not the *terminal*, the terminal is `gnome-terminal`. You will have to use something like this: `gnome-terminal -- bash -c '/path/to/file/; bash'`

Comment: Yep that works, thank you!